# How to name excel files as the names of the data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, loops, openxlsx

I have a large list with more than 100 data frames in it. For simplification I show a list with three data frames (dummy data). I would like to write each data frame into an excel file by using openxlsx. I already created a loop, in which each data frame becomes on excel file, but I want to name each excel file as the name of the data frame. How can I get each excel file named as the data frame in the list??
So `DF1` should become DF1.xlsx. `DF2` should become DF2.xlsx. `DF` should become DF3.xlsx.But at the moment each excel file is name 1,2 or 3. 
My loop:

```
for (i in (1:3)) {write.xlsx(listDF[i],file=paste(i,".xlsx"))}
```

```
# dummy data
listDF <- list(
  DF1 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TGX", "TGX", "TGX", "TGX"),
    RC = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(0, 3, 4, 0),
    RC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3)
  ),
  DF2 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TBF", "TBF", "TBF", "TBF"),
    RC = c(2, 1, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(4, 3, 4, 0),
    RC.norm = c(1, 3, 3, 3),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3)
  ),
  DF3 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TZW", "TZW", "TZW", "TZW"),
    RC = c(4, 3, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(1, 3, 2, 0),
    RC.norm = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 7, 5, 3)
  )
```

```
    listDF 

    # $DF1
    #   sample  RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TGX    0     0       0          0
    # 2  TGX    1     3       3          3
    # 3  TGX    2     4       3          3
    # 4  TGX    3     0       3          3

    # $DF2
    #   sample RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TBF   2     4       1       0
    # 3  TBF   1     3       3       3 
    # 4  TBF   2     4       3       3
    # 5  TBF   3     0       3       3

    # $DF3
    #   sample  RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TZW    4     1       1          0
    # 2  TZW    3     3       1          7
    # 3  TZW    2     2       1          5
    # 4  TZW    3     0       1          3
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names of list elements can be accessed as using `names()`

```
names(listDF)
[1] "DF1" "DF2" "DF3"
```

Your loop needs to be modified to:

```
for (i in (1:3)) {write.xlsx(listDF[i],file=paste0(names(listDF)[i],".xlsx"))}
```

Also note that using `paste` generates a whitespace between your DF name and .xlsx. Using `paste0` discards the whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr`'s `imap` using which you can access data and name.

```
purrr::imap(listDF, ~openxlsx::write.xlsx(.x, paste0(.y, '.xlsx')))
```

Or in base using `Map` :

```
Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, listDF, paste0(names(listDF), '.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve names from a list in R you can run:

```
df_names <- names(listDF)
```

Then you can use them in your loop:

```
for (i in (1:length(listDF))) {
  write.xlsx(listDF[[i]],
             file = paste0(df_names[i], ".xlsx"))
}
```

Note that you can refer to your data frames as `listDF[[]]` (to return a data.frame, not a list, see the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-intro.html#Lists)) and it's generally better to store files without spaces, so use `paste0` instead of `paste` (see the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html)).

### lapply

If you would like to use `lapply`, it would be probably necessary to write a function like `lapply(listDF, function(i) {...})`, where `i`'s are your data frames.

Or, probably you can iterate over indexes and get data frames names inside `lapply` like that:

```
lapply(seq_along(listDF),
       function(i) {write.xlsx(listDF[[i]],
                      paste0(names(listDF)[[i]], ".xlsx"))
                   }
)
```